# if statement returning a value not working for UiLabel

Tags: swift, if-statement

my fairly new to swift and programming, I'm trying to display a value from an if statement. Here is my func within my UiLabel. I've tried a few variations along the same lines but it only every returns "calculate.fuelTank" it never seems to trigger the second part to my IF statement?

```
@IBOutlet weak var startingFuelDisplay: UILabel!  //not working yet
    func refreshUiopeningFuel() {

        if calculate.totalFuel <= Double(calculate.fuelTank) {

            print (Double(calculate.fuelTank)) // FuelTank

        } else {

            print (calculate.totalFuel) // TotalFuel
        }
```

Do I need to add a bool argument to trigger "else"? I have also tried using the "return" function with initialised string which included the value I was trying to extract, finally I need this to work for another display.

here is my full view controller code (i'm new I'm sure it could be cleaner)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let calculate = Inputs ( raceLaps: 13, fuelRate: 3.7, fuelTank: 110, laptime: 85.456, tyreWear: 0.05 )

    @IBOutlet weak var rate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var laps: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tank: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tyreWear: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var laptime: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var cancelKeyboard: UITapGestureRecognizer!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    //Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
        view.endEditing(true)

            }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        refreshUiFuel()
        refreshUiStops()
        refreshUiTyreLife()
        refreshUiTyreLifeLaps()
        refreshUiopeningFuel()
        refreshUiBoxOnLap ()


    }



    @IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {
        if let rateVal = Double(rate.text!),
            tankVal = Int(tank.text!),
            lapVal = Int(laps.text!),
            wearVal = Double(tyreWear.text!),
        laptimeVal: Float = 85.456 {
                let fuelModel = Inputs(raceLaps: lapVal, fuelRate: rateVal, fuelTank: tankVal, laptime: laptimeVal, tyreWear: wearVal )
                totalFuelDisplay.text = ("\(Double(fuelModel.totalFuel))")
                totalStopsDisplay.text = ("\(Int(fuelModel.totalStops))")
                tyreLifeDisplay.text = ("\(Int(fuelModel.tyreChangesRaceDistanceTotal))")
                tyreLifeLapsDisplay.text = ("\(Int(fuelModel.tyreLife))")
                startingFuelDisplay.text = ("\(refreshUiopeningFuel())")
        }
        else {
            totalFuelDisplay.text = "missing value"
            totalStopsDisplay.text = "missing value"
            tyreLifeDisplay.text = "missing value"
            tyreLifeLapsDisplay.text = "missing value"
            startingFuelDisplay.text = "missing Value"
        }

                   }

    @IBOutlet weak var totalFuelDisplay: UILabel!
    func refreshUiFuel()->String {
        return totalFuelDisplay.text!
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var totalStopsDisplay: UILabel!
    func refreshUiStops()->String {
        return totalStopsDisplay.text!
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tyreLifeDisplay: UILabel!
    func refreshUiTyreLife()->String {
        return tyreLifeDisplay.text!
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var tyreLifeLapsDisplay: UILabel!
    func refreshUiTyreLifeLaps()->String {
        return tyreLifeLapsDisplay.text!
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var pitOnLapDisplay: UILabel!
    func refreshUiBoxOnLap () {

    }



    @IBOutlet weak var startingFuelDisplay: UILabel!  //not working yet
        func refreshUiopeningFuel() ->Double {

            print(calculate.fuelTank)
            print(calculate.totalFuel)

            if calculate.totalFuel <= Double(calculate.fuelTank) {

                return Double(calculate.fuelTank) // FuelTank

            } else {

                return calculate.totalFuel // TotalFuel
            }


  }
}
```

all helped welcomed

Comment: What do you see if you print the two values you're comparing just before you compare them?

Comment: Need a lot more information. Are you trying to get console output in the Xcode debug area, which is what `print` does, or do you want the `UILabel` `startingFuelDisplay` to update its display? What causes `refreshUiopeningFuel` to get called? Nothing you've shown here. Do you mean to make it an `@IBAction` function? Associated with a button tap perhaps?

Comment: Also, there is no such thing as a function "within" an IBOutlet object. Your function `refreshUiopeningFuel()` lies *alongside* your `UILabel` within the containing class, probably `class ViewController: UIViewController`. There's nothing to tie them together yet, so describe it in terms of functionality so we can tell you what to do.

Comment: I found a little error earlier in my code on button press action, I declared the fuelTank as the result . I have now amended that with "startingFuelDisplay()" now in the console output i see the values prior to func are preset values i set in the code.

Comment: Update your post to reflect the changes you have made. Or Answer your own question if you have it working now.

Comment: When you say "preset values", what are the actual numbers?

Comment: Show us the console output (from those `print()` statements) that's printed in the case where you expect the `else` clause to trigger.

Comment: preset for "fuelTank" is 110 and "totalFuel" is a double but by default is 48.1. Just cannot figure this out, the code I have runs but just don't get the correct result.

Comment: as requested print output is                                                                        "110" 
"48.1"

Comment: So, 48.1 is less than Double(110).  That suggests that there's nothing wrong with the `if` statement.  What do you **really** want to have happen?

Comment: i want the calculated values from user inputs, i need to tap into the results within the calculate function within fuel model. My current results seems to be bypassing the maths and taking the presets

Comment: OK, but where do you ever change the preset values within the "calculate" object?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the natural real-world logic, it appears you've simply reversed the if/else logic. It would seem that if `totalFuel` is less than the tank's capacity (the `if` clause), you should return `totalFuel` in that case, and return the tank capacity in the `else` clause.

Comment: no wasn't that, back to the drawing board, may have to do this another way